# Google Map not Working when I generate Signed APK in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

When generate apk through this command **ionic cordova build android --prod --release** then google Map not show , only white screen show in ionic App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved it --**

1.Remove pagename.module.ts file in app

2.Remove import { IonicApp } from 'ionic-angular'; in pagename.ts file

3.Remove @IonicPage() from pagename.ts file

4.And Run the command ionic cordova build android --prod --release its Working in my app

Answer (score 0):

If you talk Google Maps intend `@ionic-native/google-maps`, you need to genera a new api key with your keystore for release build. Then you need to change the api key (it means you need to reinstall the maps plugin)